# how to detect which button is clicked if many buttons with same id is used in jQuery? using id only and not class

Tags: jquery

if my button is as follows

```
<input type="button" id="btnOrderLiterature" value="<%=submitButtonText %>" ng-click="addLiteratureToSession($event)" />
```

now there are many buttons with same id on a page and if I want to detect which button is clicked and change its value then how can I manage it?

Comment: _there are many buttons with same id on a page_. I stopped here.

Comment: I know its not what you want to hear but ID's are used only for single element selection. Classes are designed to accomodate what you want while acccomplishing the required functionality.

Comment: **IDs should be unique**. If people shared IDs, how would you identify them? Ask yourself this question.

Answer (score 1):

your IDs must be unique but the class can be the same for all. So add a click listener to all the elements with the same class name

```
<input type="button" id="1" value="1" class="btn"/>
<input type="button" id="2" value="2" class="btn"/>
<input type="button" id="3" value="3" class="btn"/>


$(function () {
    $(".btn").on('click', function (e) {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I think that's what you were thinking about: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/2h02svwh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this simple example using classes instead. I changed the value/text of your buttons to better illustrate the example.

```js
//your selector here is any btnOrderLiterature class
$(".btnOrderLiterature").click( function()
{
   //Here you handle what happens when 
   //the user clicks an element that holds the btnOrderLiterature class
   alert( $(this).val() ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btnOrderLiterature" value="1" ng-click="addLiteratureToSession($event)" />
<input type="button" class="btnOrderLiterature" value="2" ng-click="addLiteratureToSession($event)" />
<input type="button" class="btnOrderLiterature" value="3" ng-click="addLiteratureToSession($event)" />
<input type="button" class="btnOrderLiterature" value="4" ng-click="addLiteratureToSession($event)" />
<input type="button" class="btnOrderLiterature" value="5" ng-click="addLiteratureToSession($event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So for valid HTML the IDs have to be unique in its scope.
Please see here: [w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

So if you don't want to change your html-markup you can use another selector like:

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
    $(this).val('new value'); // $(this) is refering to the actual clicked button
});
```

**Reference**

[attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)